# Difference between at() and overloading operator [ ] C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

What is difference between `at()` and overloading `operator` `[ ]`? What is distinction in their realization except that `at()`provides bounds checking and throws an exception `out_of_range`?

Realization of `operator` `[ ]`:

```
 const int LIMIT =100;
 .......................
 int& operator[ ] (int n) const

 {
    if(n<0 || n >= LIMIT)
    {
      std::cout<<"Error index!"<<std::endl;
      exit(1);
    }
    return arr[ n ];
 }
```

Can you give an idea of realization `at()`?

Comment: `operator []` doesn't do bounds checking.  And why in the world would you `exit()` an application if there is a boundary error??

Comment: @WhiZTiM no, it is just for yourself. Want to check my understanding of difference. For full realization of `at()` , do I need to throw exception?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie guess, that I should put `throw` in my condition

Comment: Your question is confusing.  The `operator []` shouldn't be doing anything except `return arr[n]`.

Comment: There is nothing inherent in C++ that limits whether or how you implement `[]` and/or `at()` for your classes (though `[]` is limited to one parameter).  Your question only makes any sense if you're aiming to have you class follow the behaviour used in the C++ Standard LIbrary containers, such as `vector`, in which case `[]` should do no bounds checking, and `at()` should indeed throw `out_of_range` when applicable.  Perhaps it will help you to know that `operator[]` is intended to give performance matching that of unchecked access to in-built "C" arrays, while `at()` is safer but slower.

Comment: @NikitaGusev That would be a better idea, `exit` is a bit harsh. It does not give your class' user the ability to recover from the error or to to save unsaved data or whatever is still left to do.

Comment: @TonyD  how I got you in case with `[ ]`, I don't need to `throw` (I just  try to make realization of it). But to be closer to `vector` and make realization of at() , I should  throw `out_of_range`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Herb Sutter's book exceptional c++ style covers this precise topic in item 1: at applies bound checks and will throw an exception where [] will perform undefined behavior when used out of bounds. We have freedom to choose which one we want to use in line with c++ philosophy that one should pay only for what one uses. at() is likely to be more expensive due to checks it will perform.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/

You can take a look at an implementation like gcc's one for this.

Comment: thanks for answer, now it's clear for me.

Comment: If you implement [] and at() for your own abstract types you're probably best advised to maintain these semantics.

Comment: will put my efforts on it, thanks one more time